# How to identify region click on imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I have to implement a functionality as mentioned below:

I have to display one cheque image at the top of my form. Now cheque image will collapse and expand as user clicks on image. So that is quite simple and can be achieved  by having 2 images, one for collapse and one for expand.

Now the twist is that there are 2 numbers shown on the image ,routing number and some other number when user starts typing in any edit box the corresponding number on cheque image will get highlighted . Vice a Versa if users clicks on this number displayed on check the cursor should shift to particular edit box .

Dilemma for me is that if user is clicking on any other region of cheque it should expand or collapsed , however if user is clicking on routing number or other number the other event should shoot that will take care of placing the cursor in corresponding edit box . Please suggest how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help :-

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
            ImageVIew view ...;
            Drawable drawable = view.getBackground();
            Rect myRect = drawable.getBounds();
            if (myRect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()))
            {
                //you can compare the distance and choose what to do !
                //means pressed on your imageView
            }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```